# Class not found CallableProcessingInterceptor: migrated to 3.1.4

Tags: maven, spring-3

Stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /tsl threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.async.CallableProcessingInterceptor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1062)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4935)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5257)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

have no idea about this..same project with maven is giving this error and without using maven works fine..

updatepolicy is never in pom.xml

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>tundra</groupId>
      <artifactId>tsl</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
        <build>
            <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
            <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.14.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
                <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
                <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
          <pluginRepository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
          </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
     <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>          
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>          
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>          
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

was working fine with spring 3.0.5..right after migrating to 3.1.4 this error shows up..some questions and articles says it is in 3.2.x that where I am confused..not using anything higher than 3.1.4..any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post the `<dependencies>` section of your POM, specifically the Spring dependencies you are pulling in.

Comment: @PeterMularien added dependencies I am using

Comment: There must be something you're not telling us here. This class is only resident in Spring 3.2.0+, and yet you have no dependencies referring to Spring 3.2.0+. Did you attempt to upgrade to Spring 3.2.x and may have forgotten to clean the Tomcat working directory?

Comment: yes. I updated to 3.2.x and then went back to 3.1.4. I think I did clean everything let me try it again. did clean still, it gives me same error!

Comment: Finally its working! deleted the repository and ran again..! Thanks man..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427392/erorr-when-deployment-to-tomcat/15427465#15427465) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427392/erorr-when-deployment-to-tomcat) - the answer is one of:

- You have some old JAR files remaining in your deployment directory from an attempted upgrade to Spring 3.2.x (where this class exists), followed by a downgrade to Spring 3.0.x or 3.1.x
- You have conflicting dependencies, with different versions of Spring (i.e. some 3.1 and some 3.2 dependencies). This can be determined by running `mvn dependency:tree` from your build directory. Look for conflicting versions.

In fact, I did notice that your project has issues with conflicting versions, `dependency:tree` does show conflicts with some of the Spring components:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[...snip...]
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
```

Although you are trying to include Spring 3.1.4.RELEASE, you can see some components are pulling in different versions since you haven't specified them specifically.

This isn't causing the issue in this question, but it may over time lead to similar problems.