# Spring can't autowire Webapp context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My IDE(intelliJ) complains that "Could not autowire no beans of type WebApplicationContext found", and when I run the tests it fails while creating mockMvc;

```
"ClassNotFoundException:org.springframework.web.context.request.async.CallableProcessingInterceptor
```

Any Ideas what should be missing?

This is how my test application context file looks like;

```
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:property-placeholder location="
        file:src/main/resources/conf/${user.name}/my.properties,
        file:src/main/resources/conf/${user.name}/my-junit.properties"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="my.main.package"/>

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/SomeOtherContext.xml"/>
```

And this is how my test class looks like;

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({
   "file:/src/test/resources/META-INF/MyTestContext.xml"
})

public class ServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext context;

@Before
public void init() throws NoSuchFieldException {

    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();

}


}
```

And POM file is something like this(below is a combination of parent and child POM to show the content);

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jibx-run</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
        <artifactId>jconnect</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit-addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-addons</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Parent Pom is ;

```
   <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>utf-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <schema.dir>src/main/resources/xsd</schema.dir>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
    <jconnect.version>6.0</jconnect.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jibx-run</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <!-- xpp3 dependency includes a core javax.xml.namespace.QName class -->
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconnect</artifactId>
            <version>${jconnect.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit-addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-addons</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Add the spring-web.jar to your project (from spring 3.2). make sure you don't mix spring versions. `<context:annotation-config .. />` is already implied by `<context:component-scan />`

Comment: @M. Deinum I use spring version 3.1 all over the project and added the spring-web.jar but still have the samr error

Comment: Are you using Maven or some other dependency tool to bring in your jars? If so, consider posting those details here. `CallableProcessingInterceptor` comes from spring-web.jar, and per the first error, it is not being found.  Once you've resolved that, you might check out these similar questions/answers if still having issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108478/class-not-found-callableprocessinginterceptor-migrated-to-3-1-4

Comment: @kaliatech I added the pom file could you check

Comment: Do you have a parent POM? ...because you have not specified versions for a number of the dependencies.

Comment: You are pulling in Spring 3.2 dependencies, as the ClassNotFound is referring to a Spring 3.2 class. Post the output for `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: @kaliatech I added parent POM

Comment: When I try to use version 3.2 only for spring-web jar then I get no method def found error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Second Answer after Parent POM Added**

Your parent POM is pulling in multiple versions of the Spring Framework. Specifically:

Parent POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Project POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

You can not mix framework library versions.

**Original Answer**

Aaron's answer is very useful to debug.   M. Deinum's comment above might also be quite 
relevant, as I'm not longer certain the missing class is included in 3.1.  I can't find it until 3.2 was released. It's possible that you have conflicting jars due to messing with versions while debugging.

Perhaps try 'mvn clean' then 'mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`or`mvn package`. You can then review the complete list of jar files that maven thinks that you need. In particular, check for mismatched or duplicate versions of the Spring libraries.

You mention using an IDE as the beginning of your question. Perhaps your IDE is not configured to use the complete maven dependency list in it's classpath when running tests.

Comment: if I change spring-web and spring test to 3.2 then i get no method def found error

Comment: You would also need to remove, what I think is a very old, spring- mock dependency. I think spring-mock was replaced by spring-test in newer framework versions.  If that also doesn't work, then you should consider updating your question or creating a new question with details about the missing no method def found error. At this point, there is not enough info to help.

Comment: tnx so I can keep spring core, security, mvc and other libraries at 3.1? and only keep spring test and spring-web 3.2 ?

Comment: no. Do not mix spring framework dependency versions. Either specifiy everything as 3.1, or everything as 3.2  If you are using 3.1 and everything is correct, you will not see the missing class error in your question.

Comment: tnx When I removed the spring-mock it worked even with mixed libraries

Comment: BTW, it works but intelllij still complains that it cant autowire webapp context, any idea on that?

Answer (score 3):

The first step to debug this: Write a unit test which loads the class as a resource, i.e.:

```
 @Test
 public void testClassLoading() {
     Enumeration<URL> urls = getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("org/springframework/web/context/request/async/CallableProcessingInterceptor.class");
     int count = 0;
     while( urls.hasMoreElements() ) {
         System.out.println( urls.nextElement() );
         count ++;
     }
     assertEquals( "Expected this class exactly once", 1, count );
 }
```

I have a couple of these in my unit tests to prevent against simple class path issues (duplicate or missing dependencies).

Note: This must be a standalone unit test class. If Spring fails to initialize, it's possible that no test methods can be run.

Now you found that the test return 0 which means the class isn't on the classpath.

The second step is then to find which JAR contains this class: Go to http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav and enter the class name into the correct field.

The search yields that this class is in `org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.x.RELEASE` and not in 3.1.

Conclusion: Something is wrong with your class path. You probably mix Spring versions. Don't do that.

Comment: See my edits. That means the necessary JAR isn't on the class path. You will need to fix your project setup.

Comment: I believe the missing class is only found in the 3.2.x releases: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cc%3A%22CallableProcessingInterceptor%22